# Titanium - Requested module not found: alloy/controllers/undefined

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I'm just following the guide on appcelerator, but something doesn't work.
This is the error message:

```
TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,29887] - In ti:/module.js:280,9
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,29887] - Message: Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: alloy/controllers/undefined
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,29888] - Source:       throw new Error("Requested module not found: " + request);
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at ti:/module.js:280: Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: alloy/controllers/undefined
```

index.js:

```
$.index.open();

var myBooks = Alloy.Collections.books;

var book = Alloy.createModel("books",{
    title: "Great Expectations",
    author: "Charles Dickens"
});

myBooks.add(book);
book.save();

function showBook(event){
    console.log( event );
    var selectedBook = event.source;
    var args = {
        title: selectedBook.title,
        author: selectedBook.author
    };

    var bookView = Alloy.createController("bookdetails". args).getView();
    bookView.open();
}
```

bookdetails.js:

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};
$.titleLabel.text = args.title || "Default Title";
$.authorLabel.text = args.author || "Default author";
```

Comment: is that a fullstop ? `var bookView = Alloy.createController("bookdetails". args).getView(); ?` There should be a comma.

Comment: Yes, it's a mistake. I'll let you know if the error comes from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining a new view with the controller if you want to pass multiple parameters as arguments to the controller they they need to be delimited in comma separated list.

```
Alloy.createController('viewname', args).getView();
```

Your full stop is causing alloy to throw the exception.